# How to call Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/addDevice.html',
    controller: ModalCtrl
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (newDevice) {

});
```

I will implement it in this way:

```
app.controller("ModalCtrl", function( $scope, $modalInstance ) {

});
```

But only this way is accepted:

```
var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

};
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When registering a controller the following way:

```
app.controller("ModalCtrl", function( $scope, $modalInstance ) {

});
```

You haven't declared a `ModalCtrl` variable so in the following case `ModalCtrl` would be undefined:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/addDevice.html',
    controller: ModalCtrl
});
```

You can provide the controller name as a string instead:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/addDevice.html',
    controller: 'ModalCtrl'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having issues because the value for your controller name needs to be in quotes -

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/addDevice.html',
    controller: 'ModalCtrl' // <-- this needs to be in quotes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is defining your controller class:

```
 var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

 };
```

you need to create an instance of the class:

```
  var instance = new ModalCtrl(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cotes for the controller name. That will work fine.